# Driftsort an array

Tags: code-golf, sorting

Driftsort is a simple way to "sort" an array. It works by "sliding" or "rotating" the elements over in the array until the array is sorted, or until the array fails to be sorted.

Let's walk through two examples. First, consider the array `[10, 2, 3, 4, 7]`. Since the array is not sorted, we rotate it once. (This can happen in either direction, so long as it remains the same direction.) Then, the array becomes:

```
[7, 10, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is not sorted, so we rotate again.

```
[4, 7, 10, 2, 3]
```

And again:

```
[3, 4, 7, 10, 2]
```

And a final time:

```
[2, 3, 4, 7, 10]
```

And it's sorted! So the array `[10, 2, 3, 4, 7]` is driftsortable. Here are all the rotations of the array, for clarity:

```
[10, 2, 3, 4, 7]
[7, 10, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 7, 10, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 7, 10, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 7, 10]
```

Consider now the array `[5, 3, 9, 2, 6, 7]`. Look at its rotations:

```
[5, 3, 9, 2, 6, 7]
[7, 5, 3, 9, 2, 6]
[6, 7, 5, 3, 9, 2]
[2, 6, 7, 5, 3, 9]
[9, 2, 6, 7, 5, 3]
[3, 9, 2, 6, 7, 5]
```

None of these arrays are sorted, so the array `[5, 3, 9, 2, 6, 7]` is not driftsortable.

---

**Objective** Given a nonempty array/list of integers as input to a program/function, implement driftsort on the input and output it, or output a falsey value (**or** an empty array/list) if it cannot be driftsorted. The integers are bound to your languages max/min, but this must be at least 255 for the max, and 0 for the min.

You may use built-in sorting methods, but not a built-in which solves the challenge.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes.

### Test cases

```
input => output
[1] => [1]
[5, 0, 5] => [0, 5, 5]
[3, 2, 1] => false
[0, 9, 3] => false
[1, 2, 3, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 1, 2, 3] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 2, 0, 2] => false
[5, 3, 9, 2, 6, 7] => false
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[75, 230, 30, 42, 50] => [30, 42, 50, 75, 230]
[255, 255, 200, 200, 203] => [200, 200, 203, 255, 255]
```

Comment: An easy way to check if a list is driftsortable is if `sorted(l)` is a contiguous sublist of `l+l`.

Comment: Just to clarify: If our language supports negative integers, they can occur in the input, yes?

Comment: @Dennis that is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't this be called `shiftsort`?

Comment: @FilipHaglund I thought about calling it that, but it may cause confusion with the `shift` operation that removes the first element of an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṙỤċṢȧṢ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmZ4bukxIvhuaLIp-G5og&input=&args=WzI1NSwgMjU1LCAyMDAsIDIwMCwgMjAzXQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmZ4bukxIvhuaLIp-G5ogrDh-KCrOG5hOKCrOG5m-KAnA&input=&args=WzFdLCBbNSwgMCwgNV0sIFszLCAyLCAxXSwgWzAsIDksIDNdLCBbMSwgMiwgMywgNF0sIFs0LCAxLCAyLCAzXSwgWzAsIDIsIDAsIDJdLCBbNSwgMywgOSwgMiwgNiwgN10sIFswLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwXSwgWzc1LCAyMzAsIDMwLCA0MiwgNTBdLCBbMjU1LCAyNTUsIDIwMCwgMjAwLCAyMDNd).

#### How it works

```
ṙỤċṢȧṢ  Main link. Argument: A (list)

 Ụ      Grade up; return the indices of A, sorted by their corresponding values.
ṛ       Rotate A by each index, yielding the list of all rotations.
   Ṣ    Yield A, sorted.
  ċ     Count the number of times sorted(A) appears in the rotations.
        This gives 0 if the list isn't driftsortable.
    ȧṢ  Logical AND with sorted(A); replaces a positive count with the sorted list.
```

Comment: Ahem, 19 bytes of UTF8.

Comment: Jelly has a custom [code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) that encodes each of the 256 characters it understands as single bytes. (It's 16 bytes with UTF-8 btw.)

Comment: @Dennis: you should copy/paste this in all your Jelly submissions to prevent us (ie, ones who didn't knew this before) from making the same comments ? ;)

Answer (score 18):

## Ruby, 33

```
->a{a.any?{a.sort==a.rotate!}&&a}
```

`a.any?` fires up to once for each element in the array, except it stops (and returns true) as soon as the array has been mutated into a sorted state. If this happens, we return the mutated array. Otherwise we return the false value that `any?` returns.

Comment: This is super clever, particularly the in-place rotate. Nice work!

Comment: Alas, my own Ruby answer has been bested. +1

Comment: Ah yes, the old "sort it until you can tell if it's able to be sorted" technique.

Answer (score 14):

### Python 2, 51 bytes

```python
lambda l:sorted(l)*(map(cmp,l[-1:]+l,l).count(1)<3)
```

Doesn't bother rotating. Instead, sorts the list, then sees if the original is drift-sortable by checking if there's at most one decrease among consecutive elements of the cyclified list. The count is `<3` because `map` pads the shorter list with `None` at the end, adding a fake decrease.

Comment: `[1, 3, 2, 4]` only has one decrease among consecutive elements but it's not drift-sortable.

Comment: @Neil Oh shoot.

Comment: @Neil I think this fixes it. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Aw we `<3` you too

Comment: I can't say I'm expert at Python but that seems reasonable assuming the `<3` is to avoid having to precisely rotate the list.

Comment: What does the `cmp` do in `map`?

Comment: @R.Kap Return 1 if positive 0 if 0 -1 if negative

Comment: What Python version are you using? I just tried using `cmp` and I get a `NameError` in Python 3.5.

Comment: @R.Kap `cmp` was removed from python 3, it works in python 2.

Comment: Right, this is Python 2 only, fixed.

Answer (score 10):

### Pyth, 9 bytes

```
*SQ}SQ.:+
```

Explanation:

```
           - Q = eval(input())
         + -    Q+Q
       .:  -   sublists(^)
   }       -  V in ^
    SQ     -   sorted(Q)
*SQ        - ^ * sorted(Q) (return sorted(Q) if ^ True)
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aSQ%7DSQ.%3A%2B&input=%5B5%2C0%2C5%5D&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B5%2C+0%2C+5%5D%0A%5B3%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A%5B0%2C+9%2C+3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B4%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B0%2C+2%2C+0%2C+2%5D%0A%5B5%2C+3%2C+9%2C+2%2C+6%2C+7%5D%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%5D%0A%5B75%2C+230%2C+30%2C+42%2C+50%5D%0A%5B255%2C+255%2C+200%2C+200%2C+203%5D&debug=0)

[Or use a test suite!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aSQ%7DSQ.%3A%2B&input=%5B5%2C0%2C5%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B5%2C+0%2C+5%5D%0A%5B3%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A%5B0%2C+9%2C+3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B4%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B0%2C+2%2C+0%2C+2%5D%0A%5B5%2C+3%2C+9%2C+2%2C+6%2C+7%5D%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%5D%0A%5B75%2C+230%2C+30%2C+42%2C+50%5D%0A%5B255%2C+255%2C+200%2C+200%2C+203%5D&debug=0)

Comment: I think you mean substrings (sublists) for `.:`. Combinations would include non-contiguous elements.

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab, <s>61</s> <s>47</s> 41 bytes

Thanks @Suever for -6 bytes!

```
@(a)sort(a)+0*min(strfind([a,a],sort(a)))
```

If `strfind([a,a],sort(a))` tries to find the sorted input vector as a 'substring' of the unsorted, that was appended to itself. If true, the input is driftsortable and we get a vector of length 2, if not we get a empty vector. `min` just transforms this to an number / empty vector. Adding the sorted vector to 0 just displays it, adding it to an empty vector throws an error.

Comment: Does the substring check handle `[2, 3]` not being a sublist of `[12, 34]`?

Comment: Yes, each integer array can also interpreted as string, where each number is treated as one character, no matter how big the number.

Comment: @flawr My interpretation is that `strfind` can work directly with numbers, not only with chars (even though that's not documented). If the numbers were being interpreted as chars they would be limited to `65535` (try for example `+char(1e5)`)

Comment: @LuisMendo You are right, it even works with floating point numbers. Note that numers above 65535 will just be displayed as a space when considered as part of a string.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>71</s> <s>66</s> 52 bytes

```
x->(y=sort(x))∈[circshift(x,i)for i=1:endof(x)]&&y
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an array and returns an array or a boolean. To call it, assign it to a variable.

For an input array *x*, we construct the set of all rotations of *x* and check whether the sorted version *x* is an element of that list. If it is, we return *x* sorted, otherwise we return false.

Saved 19 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>72</s> <s>70</s> 65 bytes

```
a=>a.map(y=>{c+=x>y;x=y},x=a.slice(c=-1))|c<1&&a.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

Returns `0` on failure. Previous <s>85</s> <s>83</s> 80-byte version avoided calling `sort`:

```
a=>a.map((y,i)=>{x>y&&(c++,j=i);x=y},x=a.slice(c=-1))|c<1&&a.splice(j).concat(a)
```

Edit: Saved 2 bytes by initialising `c` to `-1` instead of `0`. Saved 5 bytes by switching from `reduce` to `map`, sigh...

Comment: See the edit ;)

Comment: Call to sort for numbers is incorrect. Check on the sample `[10, 2, 3, 4, 7]`.

Comment: This code also failes 3 tests: `[1]`, `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and `[75, 230, 30, 42, 50]`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Sorry about the `sort` oversight, which caused the third test failure. The other two test failures were caused by me over-golfing; I've reverted to the previous version.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 + 1 = <s>17</s> 16 bytes

Ugh, the other golfing languages are blowing this out of the water. However, since I've already written it...

```
L#gI$<gPBPOgYgy
```

Takes input as space-separated command-line arguments. Requires `-p` or another array-formatting flag to display the result legibly rather than concatenated. The false case outputs an empty string, which is visible by virtue of the trailing newline.

```
                 Implicit: g is array of cmdline args; y is empty string
L#g              Loop len(g) times:
         POg       Pop the first item from g
      gPB          Push it onto the back of g
    $<             Fold on < (true if g is now sorted)
   I        Yg     If true, yank g into y
              y  Autoprint y
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

Code:

```
DgFÀÐ{Qi,}}0
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RGdGw4DDkHtRaSx9fTA&input=WzI1NSwgMjU1LCAyMDAsIDIwMCwgMjAzXQ).

Answer (score 3):

### [Snowman 1.0.2](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang/releases/tag/v1.0.2-beta), 27 bytes

```
((}#AsO|##aC,as|aLNdE`aR*))
```

This is a subroutine that takes input from and outputs to the current permavar.

[Try it online!](http://snowman.tryitonline.net/#code=Ly8gdGhlIGJlbG93IHN0cmluZyAoY2RlZmFiKSBpcyB0aGUgaW5wdXQuIEluIFNub3dtYW4sIHN0cmluZ3MgYXJlIHJlYWxseSBqdXN0Ci8vIGFycmF5cyBvZiBBU0NJSSBjb2Rlcy4gSSdtIHVzaW5nIGEgc3RyaW5nIGhlcmUgYmVjYXVzZSBpdCdzIHZlcnkgYW5ub3lpbmcKLy8gdG8gcHJvZHVjZSBhcnJheXMgb2YgY29uc3RhbnQgbnVtYmVycyBpbiBTbm93bWFu4oCUYnV0ICJjZGVmYWIiIGV4cGFuZHMgdG8KLy8gWzk5IDEwMCAxMDEgMTAyIDk3IDk4XS4gRm9yIGFuIGV4YW1wbGUgb2YgYSBmYWxzeSB0ZXN0IGNhc2UsIHRyeSBjaGFuZ2luZwovLyAiY2RlZmFiIiB0byBzb21ldGhpbmcgbGlrZSAiY2VkYWZiIi4KfiJjZGVmYWIiKgoKLy8gaGVyZSdzIHRoZSBzdWJyb3V0aW5lIGNhbGw6CigofSNBc098IyNhQyxhc3xhTE5kRWBhUiopKQoKLy8gbm93IHdlIG91dHB1dCB0aGUgcmVzdWx04oCUZW1wdHkgYXJyYXkgaXMgcmV0dXJuZWQgZm9yIHRoZSBmYWxzeSB2YWx1ZSAoYWthCi8vIGVtcHR5IHN0cmluZywgc28gbm90aGluZyB3aWxsIGJlIHNlbnQgdG8gU1RET1VUKQojc1A&input=)

```
((                       ))  subroutine
  }                          set our active variables b, e, and g:
                              .[a] *[b] .[c]
                              .[d]      *[e]    (* represents an active variable)
                              .[f] *[g] .[h]
   #                         store the input in variable b
    AsO                      sort in-place
       |                     swap b with g; now sorted input is in g
        ##                   store the input again in b and e
          aC                 concat; now the input doubled is in b and e is empty
            ,                swap e/g; now b has 2*input and e has sorted input
             as              split 2*input on sort(input) and store result in g
               |             bring the result up to b (we no longer care about g)
                aLNdE        take length and decrement; now we have 0 in b if the
                               array is not driftsortable and 1 if it is
                     `aR     repeat e (the sorted array) b times:
                               if b is 0 (nondriftsortable), returns [] (falsy)
                               otherwise (b=1), returns sorted array unchanged
                        *    put this back into the permavar
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES6, <s>48</s> <s>45</s> 43 chars

```
x=>~(x+[,x]).indexOf(x.sort((a,b)=>a-b))&&x
```

Test:

```
f=x=>~(x+[,x]).indexOf(x.sort((a,b)=>a-b))&&x
;`[1] => [1]
[5, 0, 5] => [0, 5, 5]
[3, 2, 1] => false
[0, 9, 3] => false
[1, 2, 3, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 1, 2, 3] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 2, 0, 2] => false
[5, 3, 9, 2, 6, 7] => false
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[75, 230, 30, 42, 50] => [30, 42, 50, 75, 230]
[255, 255, 200, 200, 203] => [200, 200, 203, 255, 255]`
.split`
`.map(t => t.replace(/^(.*) => (.*)$/, "f($1)+'' == $2")).every(eval)
```

Comment: I think you can save two bytes by using `(x+[,x])` and a further byte by using `~` instead of `1+` in your condition.

Comment: @user6188402, yep, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>13</s> <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
SGthyXfa*
```

The same idea as [@flawr's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78191/51939) where we hijack `strfind` (`Xf`) to find the sorted version of the input within the concatenation of two copies of the input.

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=U0d0aHlYZmEq&input=WzQsMSw0LDNd)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly get input
S       % Sort the input
Gth     % Explicitly grab the input again and concatenate with itself
y       % Copy the sorted version from the bottom of the stack
Xf      % Look for the sorted version as a subset
a       % Gives a 1 if there were matches and 0 otherwise
*       % Multiply by the sorted array. Yields all zeros for no match and the
        % sorted array when a match was found
        % Implicitly display the stack contents
```

Comment: Can't you remove `g`? Or replace `ng` by `a`

Comment: @LuisMendo Can't replace with just an `n` because `n` could be > 1. `a` *definitely* works though. I figured there was a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 33 bytes

```
x->sum(diff([x;x]).<0)<3&&sort(x)
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IHgtPnN1bShkaWZmKFt4O3hdKS48MCk8MyYmc29ydCh4KQoKZm9yIHggaW4gKFsxXSwgWzUsMCw1XSwgWzMsMiwxXSwgWzAsOSwzXSwgWzEsMiwzLDRdLCBbNCwxLDIsM10sIFswLDIsMCwyXSwgWzUsMyw5LDIsNiw3XSwgWzAsMCwwLDAsMCwwLDBdLCBbNzUsMjMwLDMwLDQyLDUwXSwgWzI1NSwyNTUsMjAwLDIwMCwyMDNdKQogICAgcHJpbnRsbihmKHgpKQplbmQ&input=)

#### How it works

This concatenates the array **x** with itself and counts the number of pairs that are out of order, i.e. the number of contiguous subarrays **[a, b]** for which **b - a < 0**. If **c** is the number of unordered pairs of **x** itself and **t** is **1** if **x**'s last element is larger than its first, `sum` will return **2c + t**.

The array **x** is driftsortable iff **(c, t) = (1, 0)** (**x** has to be rotated to the smaller value of the only unordered pair), **(c, t) = (0, 1)** (**x** is sorted) or **(c, t) = (0, 0)** (**x** is sorted and all of its elements are equal), which is true iff **2c + t < 3**.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 39 bytes

```
l:0re:?{[0:L],!L.|rh$(L,?h-1=:L:1&.}.o.
```

I really need to add an optional argument to `$( - circular permute left` to permute more than once... this would have been 13 bytes. This will wait after implementing a stable new transpiler in Prolog.

#### Explanation

```
l:0re                                     I = a number between 0 and the length of Input
     :?{[0:L],!L.|rh$(L,?h-1=:L:1&.}      All this mess is simply circular permutating the
                                          input I times
                                    .o.   Unify the Output with that circular permutation
                                          if it is sorted, else try another value of I
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 47 bytes

Recursive function. Returns `nil` if the input array cannot be driftsorted.

```
f=->a,i=0{a.sort==a ?a:a[i+=1]?f[a.rotate,i]:p}
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>17</s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to Dennis for saving 4 bytes.*

```
{_$\_+1$#)g*}
```

An unnamed block (function) which takes and returns a list.

[Test suite.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B'%2C-%22%20%3D%3E%20%22%2F0%3D~%0A%0A%7B_%24%5C2*1%24%23)g*%7D%0A%0A~pNo%7D%2F&input=%5B1%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B1%5D%0A%5B5%2C%200%2C%205%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B0%2C%205%2C%205%5D%0A%5B3%2C%202%2C%201%5D%20%3D%3E%20false%0A%5B0%2C%209%2C%203%5D%20%3D%3E%20false%0A%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D%0A%5B4%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D%0A%5B0%2C%202%2C%200%2C%202%5D%20%3D%3E%20false%0A%5B5%2C%203%2C%209%2C%202%2C%206%2C%207%5D%20%3D%3E%20false%0A%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B0%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%5D%0A%5B75%2C%20230%2C%2030%2C%2042%2C%2050%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B30%2C%2042%2C%2050%2C%2075%2C%20230%5D%0A%5B255%2C%20255%2C%20200%2C%20200%2C%20203%5D%20%3D%3E%20%5B200%2C%20200%2C%20203%2C%20255%2C%20255%5D)

#### Explanation

This essentially uses xnor's observation that the sorted list appears in twice the original list if its drift sortable:

```
_$   e# Duplicate input and sort.
\_+  e# Get other copy and append to itself.
1$   e# Copy sorted list.
#    e# Find first position of sorted list in twice the original,
     e# of -1 if it's not found.
)g   e# Increment and take signum to map to 0 or 1.
*    e# Repeat sorted array that many times to turn it into an empty
     e# array if the input was not drift sortable.
```

Comment: @Dennis oh, looks like we came up with that independently. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 2):

## C++ 14, 242 chars

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#define b v.begin()
using namespace std;int main(){vector<int>v;int x,n=0;for(;cin>>x;++n)v.push_back(x);for(x=n;x--;rotate(b,b+1,b+n))if(is_sorted(b,b+n)){for(x:v)cout<<x<<' ';return 0;}}
```

If I can't leave output empty, 252 chars http://ideone.com/HAzJ5V

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#define b v.begin()
using namespace std;int main(){vector<int>v;int x,n=0;for(;cin>>x;++n)v.push_back(x);for(x=n;x--;rotate(b,b+1,b+n))if(is_sorted(b,b+n)){for(x:v)cout<<x<<' ';return 0;}cout<<'-';}
```

Ungolfed version http://ideone.com/Dsbs8W

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define b v.begin()

int main()
{
  vector <int> v;
  int x, n=0;

  for(;cin>>x;++n)
    v.push_back(x);

  for(x=n;x--;rotate(b,b+1,b+n))
    if(is_sorted(b,b+n))
    {
      for(x:v) cout<<x<<' ';
      return 0;
    }

  cout << '-';
}
```

PS: Based on @MichelfrancisBustillos's [idea](/a/78205/32091).

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 207 bytes

```java
int[]D(int[]i){int x,z;z=x=-1;int[]d=new int[i.length];while(++x<i.length)if(i[x]>i[(x+1)%i.length])if(z<0)z=(x+1)%i.length;else return null;if(z<0)z=0;x=-1;while(++x<d.length)d[x]=i[z++%i.length];return d;}
```

**Detailed** [*try here*](http://ideone.com/q5YrL6)

```java
// driftsort in ascending-order
int[] D(int[]i)
{
    int x = -1,z = -1;
    int[] d = new int[i.length];

    while ((++x) < i.length)
    {
        if (i[x] > i[(x+1)%i.length])
        {
            if(z < 0) z = (x+1)%i.length;
            else return null; // not driftsortable
        }
    }

    if(z < 0) z = 0;
    x = -1;
    while ((++x) < d.length)
    {
        d[x] = i[(z++)%i.length];
    }

    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 175

prints out the output as space separated values, or prints `f` for a falsey value.

```
void d(int[]a){String s;for(int v,w,x=-1,y,z=a.length;++x<z;){v=a[x];s=""+v;for(y=0;++y<z;v=w){w=a[(x+y)%z];if(v>w){s="f";break;}s+=" "+w;}if(y==z)break;}System.out.print(s);}
```

goes through all the combinations of the array of integers until it finds the valid sequence or runs out of combinations. the array isn't modified, but instead the driftsorted sequence is stored as a space delimited string.

a bit more readable:

```
void driftsort(int[]array){
    String str;
    for(int previous,current,x=-1,y,len=array.length;++x<len;){
        previous=array[x];
        s=""+previous;
        for(y=0;++y<len;previous=current){
            current=array[(y+x)%len];
            if(previous>current){
                str="false";
                break;
            }
            str+=" "+current;
        }
        if(y==len)break;
    }
    System.out.print(str);
}
```

[try it online](http://ideone.com/zQwJZ9)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 105 bytes

```
i,s;main(c,v)char**v;{c--;while(i++<c)if(atoi(v[i])>atoi(v[i%c+1]))c*=!s,s=i;while(--i)puts(v[s++%c+1]);}
```

This accepts the input integers as separate command-line arguments and prints the output list as one integer per line.

If the list isn't driftsortable, the program exits prematurely due to a floating point exception, so its empty output represents an empty list.

#### Verification

```
$ gcc -o driftsort driftsort.c 2>&-
$ ./driftsort 1 | cat
1
$ ./driftsort 5 0 5 | cat
0
5
5
$ ./driftsort 3 2 1 | cat
$ ./driftsort 0 9 3 | cat
$ ./driftsort 1 2 3 4 | cat
1
2
3
4
$ ./driftsort 4 1 2 3 | cat
1
2
3
4
$ ./driftsort 0 2 0 2 | cat
$ ./driftsort 5 3 9 2 6 7 | cat
$ ./driftsort 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 | cat
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
$ ./driftsort 75 230 30 42 50 | cat
30
42
50
75
230
$ ./driftsort 255 255 200 200 203 | cat
200
200
203
255
255
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 28

```
->a{(a*2*?,)[a.sort!*?,]&&a}
```

Returns either the sorted array, or `nil` (which is a falsy value) if the input is not drift-sortable.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 53 bytes

```
s,N=sorted,lambda x:s(x)*(str(s(x))[1:-1]in str(x+x))
```

If you want to test this head over to https://www.repl.it/languages/python3 and copy paste this:

```
s,N=sorted,lambda x:s(x)*(str(s(x))[1:-1]in str(x+x))
print(N([1,2,3,4,5,0]))
```

How it works:

- `s` is a variable storing the `sorted` python function which sorts lists
- `N` is the main function
- The input list sorted: `s(x)` is multiplied by whether or not the list is driftsortable `str(s(x))[1:-1]in str(x+x)` (thanks to @xnor)

  - This works because `[1,2,3,4]*false` results in an empty list `[]`
  - and `[1,2,3,4]*true` results in `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: In Python 2, you can shorten this to ``lambda x,s=sorted:(`s(x)`[1:-1]in`x+x`)*s(x)`` for 44 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 83 bytes

```
def f(l):g=sorted(l);return g if any(l[x:]+l[:x]==g for x in range(len(l)))else 1>2
```

This got put to shame by the other python answers, but I might as well post it anyway. I really dislike the

```
range(len(l)))
```

part. Is there a faster way to iterate through the list?

Comment: It's not much, but `l.append(l.pop(0))or g==l for _ in l` saves a byte over the range-len approach. Using a `lambda` would save 14 additional bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/Octave,  118 bytes

```
function r(a)
i=0
while (~issorted(a) && i<length(a))
    a=a([2:end 1]),i=i+1
end
if issorted(a)
    a
else
    0
end
```

Comment: I think you can already save some bytes by writing everything on one line and using `input('')`. Also avoid unnecessary spaces and parenthesis! And you can again shed some bytes by first defining `f=@issorted`.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>87</s> 80 bytes

```
param($a)0..($a.length-1)|%{if($a[$_-1]-gt$a[$_]){$c--}};(0,($a|sort))[++$c-ge0]
```

Steps through the input list `$a`, checking each pairwise element (including the last and first) to see if there is more than one decreasing pair. If the particular pair is decreasing, we decrement `$c`. Outputs either the sorted list, or single element `0`, based on the value of `$c` at the end. If more than one "bad" pair is present, then `++$c` will still be negative, otherwise it will be at least `0`, so the second element of the pseudo-ternary is chosen (`$a|sort`).

I see xnor did [something similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78182/42963), but I came up with this independently.

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 313 <s>359</s> <s>370</s> bytes

*Huge shoutout to @Qwertiy for getting this working and teaching me some great golfing methods!*

#### Golfed:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){vector<int> v;int x,c=0,s=0,y;while(cin>>x)v.push_back(x);do if(rotate(v.begin(),v.begin()+1,v.end()),c++,is_sorted(v.begin(),v.end()))s=1;while(!s&c<=v.size());if(s)for(y=0;y<v.size();y++)cout<<v[y]<<" ";else cout<<"False";}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector <int> v;
  int x, c=0, s=0, y;

  while(cin>>x)
    v.push_back(x);

  do 
    if (
      rotate(v.begin(),v.begin()+1,v.end()),
      c++,
      is_sorted(v.begin(),v.end())
    ) s = 1;
  while(!s & c <= v.size());

  if (s)
    for(y=0; y<v.size(); y++)
      cout<<v[y]<<" ";
  else
    cout<<"False";
}
```

Comment: Golfing isn't just removing spaces. `using namespace std;` is 20 chars when `std::` 6 times is 30. `bool s = False;` - why not `=0`? You can drop `return 0;`. Why are brackets here `!s&&(c<=v.size())`? Figure braces and no commas...

Comment: Wow, thanks! A Lot of stuff (like `std::` and `return 0;`) has become habit from programming classes. I really need to start checking my programs better.

Comment: Also there is a set of bugs. Why do you read until zero and put that zero into data? Why do you output to size inclusive? Why `True` and `False` instead of `true` and `false`. http://ideone.com/kVTI25 - your version, http://ideone.com/y8s44A - fixed and prepared for golfing version.

Comment: Thank you again! Caping `True` and `False` is from Python. I didn't even know you could write `if`s like that!

Comment: And much more shortened: http://ideone.com/Dsbs8W and golfed http://ideone.com/HAzJ5V (<s>255</s> 252 chars). Used C++14 for foreach loop.

Comment: @Qwertiy I yield, if you would like, I'll delete this answer so you can post it yourself, since it is more yours than mine at this point.

Comment: You don't need to delete anything.

Comment: Maybe you leave 313 chars revision? Or shorten it to 311 as you have extra linebreak ans space there?

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 47 bytes

```
[ dup dup append [ natural-sort ] dip subseq? ]
```

join the sequence onto itself, then check if the sorted rendition of the original is a subsequence.

Comment: This sounds like a philosophical haiku: `dup dup append \\ natural sort \\ dip subseq?` Even fits the 4-4-3 pattern :)

Comment: @Akiiino :D point-free languages are so poetic.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <s>55 50 61</s> 58 bytes

With 3 bytes saved thanks to Martin Büttner.

My earlier attempts did not pass all of the test case. I needed to add `Union` to avoid repetitions in list that were input in order.

```
Join@Union@Cases[NestList[RotateRight,#,Length@#],Sort@#]&
```

**Tests**

```
Join@Union@Cases[NestList[RotateRight,#,Length@#],Sort@#]&/@
{{1},{5,0,5},{3,2,1},{0,9,3},{1,2,3,4},{4,1,2,3},{0,2,0,2},{5,3,9,2,6,7},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{75,230,30,42,50},{255,255,200,200,203}}
```

> {{1}, {0, 5, 5}, {}, {}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {}, {}, {0, 0, 0,
>      0, 0, 0, 0}, {30, 42, 50, 75, 230}, {200, 200, 203, 255, 255}}

---

**Explanation**

Right rotate the input list from 1 to `n` times, where `n` is the length of the input list.  If the sorted input list is among the output rotated lists, return it; otherwise return an empty list.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, Your suggestion failed in some of the test cases, specifically, #s 3,4,7,8.

Comment: @DavidC Ah, damn, you're right, I mixed up the behaviour of `@@` and `/@` on empty lists. `Join@@` should still be shorter than `Flatten@` though.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>125</s> 117 bytes

```
int[]d(int[] m){int r=0;for(int i=0;i<m.Length-1;i++)if(m[i+1]<m[i])r++;if(r<2){Array.Sort(m);return m;}return null;}
```

ungolfed:

```
int[] driftsort(int[] m)
    {
        int r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m.Length - 1; i++)
            if (m[i + 1] < m[i])
                r++;

        if (r < 2) { Array.Sort(m); return m; }
        return null;
    }
```

there is much to get smaller here, advice would be appreciated

thanks to Erik Konstantopoulos for -8

Comment: I'm no C# expert, but I think `int[] driftsort` turns to `int[]driftsort` for -1 byte.

Comment: @ErikKonstantopoulos You are correct.

Comment: Seems like you can replace the `if()`s with `?:` ternaries, too

Comment: @cat I don't think the second `if()` can be replaced.

Comment: there must be a way to return a sorted array.

Comment: also the name is long for no reason. lol lemme fix dat

Comment: `int[] m` doesn't need a space, also, if you use C# 6, you can use a lambda and leave out the name and type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: cat i tried but i couldnt get it to work...

Answer (score 1):

## Mathcad, TBD

[image]

In Mathcad, 0 (scalar) == false.

(Equivalent) byte count is TBD until counting method agreed.  Approx 52 bytes using a byte = operator / symbol keyboard equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 98 bytes

Outputs a `1` if driftsortable, else nothing

```
$a=$argv[1];$b=$a;sort($a);foreach($a as $v){echo($a===$b?1:'');array_unshift($b, array_pop($b));}
```